Migration of ICS calendar data incomplete, looking for alternative ways to migrate
I am trying to migrate calendar data from iCloud to a Kerio Mailserver.
The customer environment is mac based, so I tried using the mac integrated calendar app to export an ICS file from iCloud and import it into the Kerio CalDav account.
Some accounts worked, some timed out. When a migration times out, the calendar starts re-syncing and ends up deleting the local data.
As with any Mac OS software there is no activity visible during the migration, so we don't exactly know what happens, all we know is, that sometimes the migration stops and never restarts.
tl;dr:
I'm looking for a way to upload ICS files to a Kerio Connect server that is more reliable then the mac calendar app. I'll take any hints and don't care if it is Mac, Windows or Linux based.
